# mongoengine: connection closed when connecting to MongoDB Atlas

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I'm working on trying to connect mongoengine to an external mongodb host (mongodb atlas):

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from mongoengine import *
import os
import bcrypt
from datetime import datetime

# Loading environmentals
load_dotenv()
secret = os.getenv('SECRET')
mongodb_uri = os.getenv('MONGODB_URI')
mongo_username = os.getenv('USERNAME')
mongo_password = os.getenv('PASSWORD')


DEBUG = True

# Creating flask instance for routing
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

# setting up cors
CORS(app, resources={r'/*': {'origins': '*'}})

# Connecting to MongoDB Atlas
connect( db="test", username=mongo_username, password=mongo_password, host=mongodb_uri )
```

On attempt to connect, i'm getting thrown back this error:

`raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: connection closed,connection closed,connection closed`

Not sure why it's not connecting.

Comment: That tends to happen when you are connecting to a server using TLS (which atlas does) but TLS is not enabled on the client.

Comment: Ah, how would I go about enabling TLS here?

Comment: Use tls=true URI option.

Comment: I've tried this and it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: Review server logs obtained from atlas. Test connection with `mongo` shell. Test connection with `pymongo` directly.